# How to add line break to XML attribute value

Tags: xml, html-encode

I want to add break 
 or something similar to XML headerText Filed

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
<results table="New_Table" 
         keyColumn="Column1"  
         defaultSortColumn="Column1" 
         defaultSortDirection="ASC" 
         enableExcelExport="true" 
         excelTemplate="~/Content/Test.xls">
  <columns>
    <column name="OWNERNAME" headerText="Owner Name" align="left" width="25"/>
  </columns>
</results>
```

I tried this by did not work:

```
<column name="OWNERNAME" headerText="Owner <br/>Name" 
        HtmlEncode="False" align="left" width="25"/>
```

Comment: Elements of any kind,  including `<br/>`, may not appear in any XML attribute values, including the attribute value of `headerText` in your example.  You can try `&#xA;` for line feed and `&#xD;` for carriage return.  See the duplicate link for further details.